# HTML5 MPEG4 video and size

Tags: html, mp4

I don´t understand why i can´t put the video to full size 100% , actually only in this case all time no show to 100 % in other cases no have any problem , my code

```
<style>
video
{
width:100%;
max-width: 100%;
height:100% !important; 
}
</style>
<video controls="controls">
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" codecs="amp4v.20.8, mp4a.40.2"'>
</video>
```

I try many times change the size and put width and height inside video tag , but the problem continue and can´t put to full size

What´s the problem for this ?

Thank´s , the best regards

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to Height : 100% to work its parent also need to have the same.